# calling and outputting a method with the echo property in OOP

Tags: php

There is such a code construction

```
abstract class Main{
    protected $name = 'Main';

    public function callMe()
    {
        return $this->foo();
    }

    public function foo()
    {
        throw new Exception('Foo Not Found');
    }

    protected function getName()
    {   
        return $this->name;
    }
}

class One extends Main
{
    public function foo()
    {
        $name = $this->getName();
        echo "Hello from class ".$name."\n";
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        echo "Two";
    }
}
```

I create an object and call the `callMe ()` method

```
$one = new One();
$one->callMe();
```

But she brings me

```
TwoHello from class
```

but not

```
Hello from class Two
```

c return all the rules work,

```
public function getName ()
{
    return 'Two';
}
```

but why does echo print `two` before the expression? if it should be assigned to a variable?

Comment: Because `One::getName()` prints `Two` instead of returning it.

Comment: Change `echo "Two";` to `return "Two";`

Comment: Echo prints right then and there and does not return anything. Return returns the value but does not print anything unless the returned value is printed.